# How does one express $\theta_{i_1\dots i_k}$ as a linear sum of $\theta_{i_{1'}\dots i_{k'}}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

Let $\{dx^{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge dx^{i_k}\mid 1\leq i_1<\cdots<i_k\leq n\}$ and $\{dx^{i_1'}\wedge\cdots\wedge dx^{i_k'}\mid 1\leq i_{1'k}<\cdots<i_{k'}\leq n\}$ be two basis for the collection of anti-symmetric $\begin{pmatrix}0\\k&\end{pmatrix}$ tensors. Let $\theta$ be one of its element. Expand it w.r.t. the first basis shown above, and we get the components , where $1\leq i_1\dots i_k\leq n$. Similarly, we get $\theta_{i_{1'}\dots i_{k'}}$. What is the relationship between $\theta_{i_1\dots i_k}$ and $\theta_{i_{1'}\dots i_{k'}}$? In other words, how does one express $\theta_{i_1\dots i_k}$ as a linear sum of $\theta_{i_{1'}\dots i_{k'}}$?

Comment: In the expression $\{dx^{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge dx^{i_k}\mid 1\leq i_1<\cdots<i_k\leq n\}$ you put the $\{\text{curly braces}\}$ outside the math tags.  That can result in mismatches of fonts and lack of proper spacing.  I put them inside the math tags (and did some other copy-editing). ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: use $dx^{i_r}=\sum_{i'_s}\frac{\partial x^{i_r}}{\partial x^{i'_s }}dx^{i'_s}$

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking as those two sets are the same, you are just using different indices. Do you want the second collection of forms to be $dx'^{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx'^{i_k}$ instead?